# React-native iOS app uploads to TestFlight but not to App Store

Tags: ios, react-native, app-store-connect, testflight

I have uploaded my app to TestFlight many times and the process works perfectly.  But when I do this, the app should appear in App Store Connect, no?  There is an old version in App Store Connect(from before my time at this company), but new ones do not get uploaded.  The version of this app is 1.0.  It has not been reviewed.  My TestFlight versions run from 1.0.2 to 2.0.1.  I have tried to delete the current version but can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Updates must go through [the review process](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/) to be published in App Store.

1. Create a new version of the application
2. Choose a build for the version
3. Submit for review

See [Submit for review](https://developer.apple.com/help/app-store-connect/manage-submissions-to-app-review/submit-for-review) for details.